# How to import a Mumble certificate from iTunes to iPhone using the iTunes file transfer?

Tags: itunes, iphone, certificate, mumble

I am using the Mumble app on my iPhone 4 and I want to transfer my Mumble certificate from the Mumble on my computer to Mumble on my phone through iTunes.

How do I import a Mumble certificate from iTunes to iPhone using the iTunes file transfer?

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Start Mumble on the device your certificate (the one you want
  to use) is stored.
- Step 2: On the menu choose Configure, then
  Certificate Wizard.
- Step 3: Select "Export current certificate", then
  click Next.
- Step 4: Click "Save As", this will open a browser window
  where you can select the name and where you want to put your
  certificate. Choose a file location and choose a file name that you
  can remember for later (I put mine on the desktop and named it
  MumbleCert), then click "Save".
- Step 5: Click Finish. This will save
  the Mumble certificate where you chose with the as the name you
  chose.
- Step 6: Connect your iPhone to your computer and start iTunes.
- Step 7: On the left menu select your device, and sync it (right click
  your iPhone's name and select sync or click the sync button on the
  bottom right of the iTunes window.
- Step 8: At the top of the main
  iTunes window where it displays the information for your phone, you
  have a number of options along the top; Summary, Info, Apps, Tones,
  etc... Select the Apps tab.
- Step 9: Scroll down to the File Sharing
  section of the Apps window. You will see two smaller sections, Apps
  on the left, and Documents on the right. In the Apps section select
  Mumble, then select "Add..." on the Documents section.
- Step 10:
  Browse to the Mumble Certificate you saved earlier, and choose
  "Open".
- Step 11: On your iPhone open the Mumble App, select
  Preferences, then Certificate, Press the + button in the top right
  then select "Import from iTunes" then select the certificate.

  You can now connect to your mumble servers using the certificate you
  moved from your computer.

Source(s): http://support.apple.com/kb/PH1693